# State Space model code from Time Series analysis Springer book, and code error from optimization

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to apply State Space model code from the book, Time Series analysis and its applications from Springer book, to my data.

The code is as below:

```
num = length(jj)
A = cbind(1,1,0,0) 
# Function to Calculate Likelihood 
Linn =function(para){ 
  Phi = diag(0,4)
  Phi[1,1] = para[1] 
  Phi[2,]=c(0,-1,-1,-1)
  Phi[3,]=c(0,1,0,0)
  Phi[4,]=c(0,0,1,0) 
  cQ1 = para[2]; cQ2 = para[3] # sqrt q11 and q22 
  cQ = diag(0,4); cQ[1,1]=cQ1; cQ[2,2]=cQ2 
  cR = para[4]
  kf = Kfilter0(num, jj, A, mu0, Sigma0, Phi, cQ, cR)
  return(kf$like) }

# Initial Parameters 
mu0 = c(.7,0,0,0); Sigma0 = diag(.04,4) 
init.par = c(1.03,.1,.1,.5) # Phi[1,1], the 2 cQs and cR 

# Estimation and Results 
est = optim(init.par, Linn,NULL, method='BFGS', hessian=TRUE, 
        control=list(trace=1,REPORT=1)) 
SE = sqrt(diag(solve(est$hessian))) 
u = cbind(estimate=est$par, SE) 
rownames(u)=c('Phi11','sigw1','sigw2','sigv'); u 

# Smooth 
Phi = diag(0,4); Phi[1,1] = est$par[1] 
Phi[2,]=c(0,-1,-1,-1); Phi[3,]=c(0,1,0,0); Phi[4,]=c(0,0,1,0) 
cQ1 = est$par[2]; cQ2 = est$par[3] 
cQ = diag(1,4); cQ[1,1]=cQ1; cQ[2,2]=cQ2 
cR = est$par[4] 
ks = Ksmooth0(num,jj,A,mu0,Sigma0,Phi,cQ,cR) 

# Plots 
Tsm = ts(ks$xs[1,,], start=1960, freq=4) 
Ssm = ts(ks$xs[2,,], start=1960, freq=4)
p1 = 3*sqrt(ks$Ps[1,1,]); p2 = 3*sqrt(ks$Ps[2,2,]) 
par(mfrow=c(2,1)) 
plot(Tsm, main='Trend Component', ylab='Trend') 
xx = c(time(jj), rev(time(jj))) 
yy = c(Tsm-p1, rev(Tsm+p1)) 
polygon(xx, yy, border=NA, col=gray(.5, alpha = .3)) 
plot(jj, main='Data & Trend+Season', ylab='J&J QE/Share', ylim=c(-.5,17)) 
xx = c(time(jj), rev(time(jj)) ) 
yy = c((Tsm+Ssm)-(p1+p2), rev((Tsm+Ssm)+(p1+p2)) ) 
polygon(xx, yy, border=NA, col=gray(.5, alpha = .3)) 

# Forecast 
n.ahead = 12 
y = ts(append(jj, rep(0,n.ahead)), start=1960, freq=4) rmspe = rep(0,n.ahead)
x00 = ks$xf[,,num]; P00 = ks$Pf[,,num] 
Q = t(cQ)%*%cQ
R = t(cR)%*%(cR) 
for (m in 1:n.ahead){ 
  xp = Phi%*%x00; Pp = Phi%*%P00%*%t(Phi)+Q 
  sig = A%*%Pp%*%t(A)+R; K = Pp%*%t(A)%*%(1/sig) 
  x00 = xp; P00 = Pp-K%*%A%*%Pp 
  y[num+m] = A%*%xp; rmspe[m] = sqrt(sig) }

plot(y, type='o', main='', ylab='J&J QE/Share', ylim=c(5,30), 
 xlim=c(1975,1984)) 
upp = ts(y[(num+1):(num+n.ahead)]+2*rmspe, start=1981, freq=4) 
low = ts(y[(num+1):(num+n.ahead)]-2*rmspe, start=1981, freq=4) 
xx = c(time(low), rev(time(upp))) 
yy = c(low, rev(upp)) 
polygon(xx, yy, border=8, col=gray(.5, alpha = .3)) abline(v=1981, lty=3)
```

Then there's error for est (Estimation and Results).

```
> est = optim(init.par, Linn,NULL, method='BFGS', hessian=TRUE, 
+             control=list(trace=1,REPORT=1)) 
Error in optim(init.par, Linn, NULL, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

This is my data  used for jj

```
jj<-c ( 102.95, 102.77, 103.06, 103.39, 102.98, 103.28, 102.64, 102.82, 102.14, 102.59, 103.12,
102.92, 103.65,     NA,     NA, 102.98, 102.86, 102.80, 102.30, 102.61, 102.83, 103.12,
102.78, 102.73, 102.46, 102.29, 102.73, 102.62, 102.56, 102.25, 102.22, 102.35, 102.45,
102.17, 102.05, 102.52, 101.87,     NA, 102.16, 102.11, 102.14, 101.61, 101.96, 101.91,
102.08, 102.35, 101.95, 101.99, 101.70, 102.00, 101.93, 101.98, 101.94, 101.96, 101.77,
102.09, 102.22, 101.70, 102.03, 102.11, 101.95, 102.31, 101.91, 101.79, 103.18, 101.88,
102.02,     NA,     NA, 101.72, 102.06, 101.98, 102.10)
```

Anyone can successfully run the code with this data provided?
The book doesn't provide data jj.